# How to Access JNDI properties from server.xml in worklight.properties?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jndi, mobilefirst-server

I'm working on a Mobile First 7.1 application.

I have a JNDI entry in my server.xml like say,

```
   <jndiEntry jndiName="MyPath/MyName" value="MyValue"/>
```

I need to access this JNDI property in my worklight.properties file. Went through the MF documentation, but nothing helped.

How do I retrieve this property in my worklight.properties so that I could use this in my adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.

Suppose, if there is a JNDI entry in **server.xml** like say,

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="MyName" value="MyValue"/>
```

Since, the values in the worklight.properties will be exposed as JNDI values finally, just declaring a variable without a value is the solution.

So, in your **worklight.properties**, just declare a name, without any values

```
MyName
```